# Retrive Multiple Dataclass in a Single Adapter Android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I'm currently new to Android development and I have some problem with this, I just made data class based on API, then that data class consist of many different class. I want to retrieve some of the class in a single adapter, can it be done? I just tried but I just can make until here.

```
package com.example.papb_tubes

import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.AsyncListDiffer
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DiffUtil
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.papb_tubes.databinding.ItemRowBinding

class WeatherAdapter(
    private val onItemClick: OnItemClickListener
):RecyclerView.Adapter<WeatherAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    private val differCallback = object : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<AreasItem>() {
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: AreasItem, newItem: AreasItem): Boolean {
            return oldItem.id == newItem.id
        }

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: AreasItem, newItem: AreasItem): Boolean {
            return oldItem == newItem
        }
    }
    private val differ=  AsyncListDiffer(this, differCallback)

    inner class ViewHolder(private val binding: ItemRowBinding) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

        fun bindKota(data: AreasItem) {
            binding.apply {
                tvNamakota.text = data.domain
            }
        }

        fun bindTemperature(data: TimesItem) {
            binding.apply {
                tvTemperatur.text = data.celcius.toString()
            }
        }

        fun bindTipe(data: Issue) {
            binding.apply {
                tvTipe.text = data.day
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val data = differ.currentList[position]
        when (data){
            is AreasItem -> holder.bindKota(data)
            is TimesItem -> holder.bindTemperature(data)
            is Issue -> holder.bindTipe(data)
        }
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            onItemClick.onItemClick(data)
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val binding = ItemRowBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(binding)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = differ.currentList.size
    interface OnClickListener<T>{
        fun onClickItem(data: T)
    }
}
```

this is the data class

```
package com.example.papb_tubes

import android.os.Parcelable
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName
import kotlinx.parcelize.Parcelize

@Parcelize
data class WeatherResponses(

    @field:SerializedName("data")
    val data: String,

    @field:SerializedName("success")
    val success: Boolean,

    @field:SerializedName("message")
    val message: String
) : Parcelable

@Parcelize
data class AreasItem(

    @field:SerializedName("coordinate")
    val coordinate: String,

    @field:SerializedName("level")
    val level: String,

    @field:SerializedName("latitude")
    val latitude: String,

    @field:SerializedName("domain")
    val domain: String,

    @field:SerializedName("description")
    val description: String,

    @field:SerializedName("id")
    val id: String,

    @field:SerializedName("type")
    val type: String,

    @field:SerializedName("region")
    val region: String,

    @field:SerializedName("longitude")
    val longitude: String,

    @field:SerializedName("tags")
    val tags: String,

    @field:SerializedName("params")
    val params: String
):Parcelable

@Parcelize
data class TimesItem(

    @field:SerializedName("datetime")
    val datetime: String,

    @field:SerializedName("h")
    val h: String,

    @field:SerializedName("type")
    val type: String,

    @field:SerializedName("value")
    val value: String,

    @field:SerializedName("day")
    val day: String,

    @field:SerializedName("celcius")
    val celcius: String,

    @field:SerializedName("fahrenheit")
    val fahrenheit: String,

    @field:SerializedName("code")
    val code: String,

    @field:SerializedName("name")
    val name: String,

    @field:SerializedName("deg")
    val deg: String,

    @field:SerializedName("card")
    val card: String,

    @field:SerializedName("sexa")
    val sexa: String,

    @field:SerializedName("kph")
    val kph: String,

    @field:SerializedName("mph")
    val mph: String,

    @field:SerializedName("ms")
    val ms: String,

    @field:SerializedName("kt")
    val kt: String
):Parcelable

@Parcelize
data class ParamsItem(

    @field:SerializedName("times")
    val times: List<TimesItem>,

    @field:SerializedName("description")
    val description: String,

    @field:SerializedName("id")
    val id: String,

    @field:SerializedName("type")
    val type: String
):Parcelable

@Parcelize
data class Issue(

    @field:SerializedName("month")
    val month: String,

    @field:SerializedName("hour")
    val hour: String,

    @field:SerializedName("year")
    val year: String,

    @field:SerializedName("day")
    val day: String,

    @field:SerializedName("timestamp")
    val timestamp: String,

    @field:SerializedName("minute")
    val minute: String,

    @field:SerializedName("second")
    val second: String
):Parcelable

@Parcelize
data class Data(

    @field:SerializedName("issue")
    val issue: Issue,

    @field:SerializedName("areas")
    val areas: List<AreasItem>
):Parcelable
```

The attempt that I tried before:

1. Using different `DifferCallBack` for every element that I want to retrieve in the adapter, but facing a problem where it comes to bind the data
2. I'm using T as the final approach to generalize all input that comes, but it still error in `private val differCallBack` especially in the `class areContentsThesame` (I don't understand why it error at `==` )
3. Want to split into different adapter but still confused how to merge / join it together

I'm Expecting that I can use:

- class of AreasItem to get the Domain,
- class of TimeItem to get the Celsius,
- class of Issues to get the day